# When is the time that ROS will support backward compatibility?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is very upset that new version of ROS have many packages run the same package but in different way or rosmake failed or something missing.

Most of them are 3rd party projects, but I can't build my own package without them.

For example: 3d_navigation, pcd_viewer...etc

I want to know when ROS will solve all these kinds of problems.

I know it's very hard, but it is very very important.

I don't want to change them for every ROS distributions.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41537/when-is-the-time-that-ros-will-support-backward-compatibility?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, what exactly you mean, but I think you are aiming at the fact that some packages only run on one ROS distribution.

There are some basic ways to fix that. You can check for the ROS version in the code and thus apply the right thing. This is obviously given that a certain required feature is in that release. However, especially for third party packages it's up to the maintainer to do so, so ROS can't really do more than enable these possibilities.

Packages that are released are compatible, so we are talking about packages currently under development, which usually run on a current ROS version. The aim is to have things like the API marked as stable (you can see that in that wiki) to ensure compatibility, but a package being developed doesn't give you these guarantees. That is the price you pay for getting new things as soon as they work. If you want compatibility, you need to take a stable subset.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-16**:
We can never ensure that all packages developed anywhere in the world are actively maintained by their developers. But, we can provide better tools for users to distinguish actively maintained packages from less mature code.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-16**:
I remember a discussion on ros-users about adding such information, at a minimum compatible ros distros, to the wiki. I'm not sure what the result of that was, though.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-16**:
I don't know of any, yet. But, there are active discussions about improvement for Groovy. Most of the needed information is available (review status, bug reporting link, etc.). It's just not conveniently displayed.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-17**:
Is there any the list of stable(means  compatible) packages or stacks? Thank you~

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-17**:
Not officially, that is what @joq was suggesting to have.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-17**:
So you(ROS team) will gather that list in the future? Thank you~

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-17**:
Right. One useful list of released packages (in this case for Fuerte) is here: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/fuerte.html